# Zend : How to get contents of a CLOB column?

Tags: php, zend-framework, clob

I have a CLOB column in a table. When i query the table and try to echo the data, i get something like

```
Resource id #102
```

I searched about this and found this [POST](http://www.mkfoster.com/2010/09/22/how-to-get-the-contents-of-an-oracle-clob-data-field-in-php/) . Tried the given solution from it in zend framework like this below:

```
$clobContent = $data['TEXT']->load();
```

$data contains the result of the query. 
But gets the following error

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function load() on a non-object
```

How do i get the contents of the CLOB in zend framework?

Answer (score 2):

Somehow after changing the db adapter from PDO_OCI to Oracle worked for me. Had read in some post that PDO_OCI had problems with reading CLOBS.

```
resources.db.adapter = oracle // in application.ini
```

The code below worked for me, not sure of it but can try this and let me know if it worked

```
$select = $this->_dbAdpt->select()
                    ->from($this->_name)
                    ->where($this->_dbAdpt->quoteInto('LOWER(URL) = ?', strtolower($url)))
                    ->where($this->_dbAdpt->quoteInto('VERSION = ?', $version))
                    ;

    $row = $this->_dbAdpt->fetchRow($select);

return $row['CONTENT']->load();
```